# как отправлять сообщение дискорд бота из другого питон файла?

Tags: python, discord.py, asyncio, discord-api

Есть дискорд бот на `discord.py`, но `bot.run(token)` указывается в конце, и я не могу просто импортировать `bot` из другого файла как в тг. В общем, есть бот который вызывает функцию `add_queue` из другого `sellbot` питон файла, пока она работает с тг и все окей: идет обработка очереди, после того как все обработалось `sellbot` просто импортирует `тг_bot` и вызывает функцию `bot.send_message()`. Но с дискордом такого сделать не получается, может у кого есть синхронная библиотека для дискорда или решение проблемы с `discord.py` или похожими? Заранее благодарю за ответ!